# Getting default value for primitive types

Tags: java, reflection, guava

I have a Java primitive type at hand:

```
Class<?> c = int.class; // or long.class, or boolean.class
```

I'd like to get a *default value* for this class -- specifically, the value is assigned to fields of this type if they are not initialized. E.g., `0` for a number, `false` for a boolean.

Is there a generic way to do this? I tried this:

```
c.newInstance()
```

But I'm getting an `InstantiationException`, and not a default instance.

Comment: This is a common problem, I wish Java would add a `default(T)` function like C#.

Comment: It's at its own an interesting question, but what do you need it for after all? Is it to set some bean properties or so? Aren't they already implicitly initialized with those default values?

Comment: @BalusC - To initial an HTML form that has a method parameters with the defaults.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

The Guava Libraries already contains that:
http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Defaults.html

Calling `defaultValue` will return the default value for any primitive type (as specified by the JLS), and null for any other type.

Use it like so:

```
import com.google.common.base.Defaults;
Defaults.defaultValue(Integer.TYPE); //will return 0
```

Comment: I would improve this answer by adding a sample code line. For example: 
`Defaults.defaultValue(long.class)` I say this because until just now I did not realize you could call `.class` on primitive types.

Comment: How to use this with the class generic type parameter `<T>`?

Comment: Generic types are never primitives and therefore the default value is always null.

Answer (score 30):

It's possible to get the default value of any type by creating an array of one element and retrieving its first value.

```
private static <T> T getDefaultValue(Class<T> clazz) {
    return (T) Array.get(Array.newInstance(clazz, 1), 0);
}
```

This way there is not need to take account for every possible primitive type, at the usually negligible cost of creating a one-element array.

Comment: Elegant, but for Array.get: "The value is automatically wrapped in an object if it has a primitive type." https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#get(java.lang.Object,%20int)

Comment: Clearly the most elegant solution.

Comment: @LoBo this is not a problem; the returned value will be an object anyhow.

Comment: `Array.get(Array.newInstance(Boolean.class, 1), 0)` returns null :(

Comment: @AquariusPower Boolean is not a primitive class; `Array.get(Array.newInstance(boolean.class, 1), 0)` returns false (as a wrapped Boolean object).

Comment: I prefer `return clazz.cast(Array.get(Array.newInstance(clazz, 1), 0));` over `(T)`  for casting. This way your IDE won't show any warnings.

Comment: This is great. I found that `void.class` will throw an exception in `newInstance`, so I check for that type before, and I also check if `Object.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)` and return null early to avoid the array creation.

Answer (score 18):

This is what I'm thinking (fails the elegance test though):

```
public class PrimitiveDefaults {
    // These gets initialized to their default values
    private static boolean DEFAULT_BOOLEAN;
    private static byte DEFAULT_BYTE;
    private static short DEFAULT_SHORT;
    private static int DEFAULT_INT;
    private static long DEFAULT_LONG;
    private static float DEFAULT_FLOAT;
    private static double DEFAULT_DOUBLE;

    public static Object getDefaultValue(Class clazz) {
        if (clazz.equals(boolean.class)) {
            return DEFAULT_BOOLEAN;
        } else if (clazz.equals(byte.class)) {
            return DEFAULT_BYTE;
        } else if (clazz.equals(short.class)) {
            return DEFAULT_SHORT;
        } else if (clazz.equals(int.class)) {
            return DEFAULT_INT;
        } else if (clazz.equals(long.class)) {
            return DEFAULT_LONG;
        } else if (clazz.equals(float.class)) {
            return DEFAULT_FLOAT;
        } else if (clazz.equals(double.class)) {
            return DEFAULT_DOUBLE;
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                "Class type " + clazz + " not supported");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @PatriceM. How would you go with an `enum` variant for this?

Comment: @Guillaume Polet : I'm not quite sure, to be honest :-).

Comment: Actually this is pretty neat. Should be the accepted answer IMO.

Comment: This is the best answer because primitive types list is explicitly defined by java architecture, there is no need to go for library for that.

Answer (score 7):

An alternative to Guava's `Defaults.java`, which lets the implementation figure out the default values (improved by using [Antag99’s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38243203/1783295)):

```
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class DefaultValue {
    /**
     * @param clazz
     *            the class for which a default value is needed
     * @return A reasonable default value for the given class (the boxed default
     *         value for primitives, <code>null</code> otherwise).
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T> T forClass(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (T) DEFAULT_VALUES.get(clazz);
    }

    private static final Map<Class<?>, Object> DEFAULT_VALUES = Stream
            .of(boolean.class, byte.class, char.class, double.class, float.class, int.class, long.class, short.class)
            .collect(toMap(clazz -> (Class<?>) clazz, clazz -> Array.get(Array.newInstance(clazz, 1), 0)));

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(DefaultValue.forClass(int.class)); // 0
        System.out.println(DefaultValue.forClass(Integer.class)); // null
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some example how to use it?

Comment: Kinda late, but isn't reflection an overkill in this situation? Could put them into the map yourself to save a lot of CPU time.

Comment: @TadeasKriz - this is just about avoiding duplicating information; and not sure that it would need such a big amount of CPU time (it’s computed only once). But I understand that it can be considered overkill.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with reflection, but it's easiest and clearest to write it out, e.g.

```
Object defaultValue(Class cls)
{
  Map defaults = new HashMap();
  defaults.put(Integer.TYPE, Integer.valueOf(0));  
  defaults.put(Double.TYPE, Double.valueOf(0));  
  defaults.put(Boolean.TYPE, Boolean.FALSE);  
  //... etc
  return defaults.get(cls);
}
```

Of course, you will probably want to move the map initialization out to a constructor or similar for once-only initialization.

Reasonably concise - it is elegant?

Comment: _You can do this with reflection_ How do you do it with reflection?

Comment: Why would you create a map if you don’t reuse it?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't an elegant way to do this.  In fact, it is not even possible to declare the signature of a method that will return the primitive values per se.

The closest you can come is something like this:

```
public Object defaultValue(Class cls) {
    if (class == Boolean.TYPE) {
        return Boolean.FALSE;
    } else if (class == Byte.TYPE) {
        return Byte.valueOf(0);
    } else if (class == Short.TYPE) {
        ...
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: The signature is simple: Object getDefaultValue(Class type)

Comment: That won't work because of the return value. int, long etc aren't `java.lang.Object`s, unless you're OK with returning wrapper classes (`java.lang.Integer`, `java.lang.Long` etc).

Comment: @ripper234 - but that returns wrapper instances not instances of the primitive types.

Comment: In fact, you can declare the signature of the method above like this: `public static <T> T defaultValue(Class<T> cls)`

Comment: @newacct - yes you can, though it won't necessarily help for the use case that I imagine the OP has in mind.

Comment: I'm ok with returning wrapper classes.

Answer (score 0):

Class variables of primitives do not need to be initialized or set with a default value. However variables declare in other scope must be initialized or you'll get compilation errors.

```
public class PrimitiveStuff {
private int aInt;
private long aLong;
private boolean aBoolean;

public PrimitiveStuff() {
    System.out.println("aInt : "  + aInt); //prints 0
    System.out.println("aLong: "+ aLong);//prints 0
    System.out.println("aBoolean: " + aBoolean);//prints false
}


public void doStuff(){
    int outherInt;
    System.out.println(outherInt); //will not compile
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new PrimitiveStuff();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this if you want default value including String data type:

```
private static Object getDefaultValue(Field field) {
        if (Number.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
            if (Double.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())
                || Float.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
                return 0.0;
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        } else if (Boolean.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
            return false;
        } else if (Timestamp.class.isAssignableFrom(field.getType())) {
            return new Timestamp(Instant.now().toEpochMilli());
        } else {
            return "NULL";
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Based on *[Jack Leow's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891970/getting-default-value-for-java-primitive-types/2892067#2892067)*, I created this class:

```
/**
   <P>{@code java InitializedObjectUtil}</P>
 **/
public class InitializedObjectUtil  {
      public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
         printDefault("boolean");
         printDefault("char");
         printDefault("byte");
         printDefault("short");
         printDefault("int");
         printDefault("long");
         printDefault("float");
         printDefault("double");
         printDefault("java.lang.AnythingAndEverythingElse");
      }
         private static final void printDefault(String s_type)  {
            Object oDflt = InitializedObjectUtil.getForClassName(s_type);
            System.out.println(s_type + " default is \"" + oDflt + "\"");
         }
      /**
         <P>The default value for a boolean is {@code false}.</P>

         <P>Viewed 1/21/2014
         <BR><CODE><A HREF="http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html">http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html</A></CODE>:</P>

         <P><B>Default Values:</B> </P>

         <P>It's not always necessary to assign a value when a field is declared. Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler. Generally speaking, this default will be zero or null, depending on the data type. Relying on such default values, however, is generally considered bad programming style. The following chart summarizes the default values for the above data types.</P>

   <PRE>{@literal
   Data Type   Default Value (for fields)
   --------------------------------------
   byte                       0
   short                      0
   int                        0
   long                       0L
   float                      0.0f
   double                     0.0d
   char                       '\u0000'
   String (or any object)     null
   boolean                    false}</PRE>

      @see  #getForClass(String) getForClass(s)
      @see  #getForClassName(String) getForClassName(s)
      @see  #DEFAULT_CHAR
      @see  #DEFAULT_BYTE
      @see  #DEFAULT_SHORT
      @see  #DEFAULT_INT
      @see  #DEFAULT_LONG
      @see  #DEFAULT_FLOAT
      @see  #DEFAULT_DOUBLE
    **/
   public static final Boolean DEFAULT_BOOLEAN = false;
   /**
      <P>The default value for a char {@code '\u0000'}.</P>

         @see  #DEFAULT_BOOLEAN
    **/
   public static final Character DEFAULT_CHAR = '\u0000';
   /**
      <P>The default value for a byte is {@code 0}.</P>

         @see  #DEFAULT_BOOLEAN
    **/
   public static final Byte DEFAULT_BYTE = 0;
   /**
      <P>The default value for a short is {@code 0}.</P>

         @see  #DEFAULT_BOOLEAN
    **/
   public static final Short DEFAULT_SHORT = 0;
   /**
      <P>The default value for a int is {@code 0}.</P>

         @see  #DEFAULT_BOOLEAN
    **/
   public static final Integer DEFAULT_INT = 0;
   /**
      <P>The default value for a long is {@code 0L}.</P>

         @see  #DEFAULT_BOOLEAN
    **/
   public static final Long DEFAULT_LONG = 0L;
   /**
      <P>The default value for a float {@code 0.0f}.</P>

         @see  #DEFAULT_BOOLEAN
    **/
   public static final Float DEFAULT_FLOAT = 0.0f;
   /**
      <P>The default value for a double {@code 0.0d}.</P>

         @see  #DEFAULT_BOOLEAN
    **/
   public static final Double DEFAULT_DOUBLE = 0.0d;
    /**
        <P>Get an object containing an initialized value for the static class-type.</P>

        @param  cls_static  May not be {@code null}.
        @return  <CODE>{@link getForClassName(String) getForClassName}(cls_static.getName())</CODE>
     **/
    public static final Object getForClass(Class cls_static)  {
       try  {
          return  getForClassName(cls_static.getName());
       }  catch(RuntimeException rtx)  {
          throw  new NullPointerException("getForClass: cls_static");
       }
    }
   /**
      <P>Get an object containing an initialized value for the type whose name is in a string.</P>

         <P>Idea from (viewed 1/2/2014)
      <BR> &nbsp; &nbsp; {@code <A HREF="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891970/getting-default-value-for-java-primitive-types/2892067#2892067">https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891970/getting-default-value-for-java-primitive-types/2892067#2892067</A>}</P>

      @param  s_type  May not be {@code null}.
      @return  If {@code s_type} is equal to<UL>
         <LI>{@code "boolean"}: {@link #DEFAULT_BOOLEAN}</LI>
         <LI>{@code "char"}: {@link #DEFAULT_CHAR}</LI>
         <LI>{@code "byte"}: {@link #DEFAULT_BYTE}</LI>
         <LI>{@code "short"}: {@link #DEFAULT_SHORT}</LI>
         <LI>{@code "int"}: {@link #DEFAULT_INT}</LI>
         <LI>{@code "long"}: {@link #DEFAULT_LONG}</LI>
         <LI>{@code "float"}: {@link #DEFAULT_FLOAT}</LI>
         <LI>{@code "double"}: {@link #DEFAULT_DOUBLE}</LI>
         <LI><I>anything else</I>: {@code null}</LI>
      </UL>
      @see  #getForClass(Class) getForClass(cls)
    **/
   public static final Object getForClassName(String s_type)  {
      try  {
         if(s_type.equals("boolean"))  {
            return  DEFAULT_BOOLEAN;
         }
      }  catch(NullPointerException npx)  {
         throw  new NullPointerException("getForClassName: s_type");
      }
      if(s_type.equals("char"))  {
         return  DEFAULT_CHAR;
      }
      if(s_type.equals("byte"))  {
         return  DEFAULT_BYTE;
      }
      if(s_type.equals("short"))  {
         return  DEFAULT_SHORT;
      }
      if(s_type.equals("int"))  {
         return  DEFAULT_INT;
      }
      if(s_type.equals("long"))  {
         return  DEFAULT_LONG;
      }
      if(s_type.equals("float"))  {
         return  DEFAULT_FLOAT;
      }
      if(s_type.equals("double"))  {
         return  DEFAULT_DOUBLE;
      }

      //Non-primitive type
      return  null;
   }
}
```