# How do I set a Field to null using reflection in java?

Tags: java, primitive-types, reflect

This might seem like a stupid question at first, just do `field.set(obj, null)`. But if the field is not an object, but a primitive, this will return an error. What I want is that it "resets" the value, no matter if it is an object, or a primitive (e.g. `String` -> `null`, `int` -> `0`, `boolean` -> `false`). I have already tried doing `field.getType().isPrimitive() ? 0 : null`, hoping that the `0` would cast to `short`, `byte`, `boolean`, etc. automatically, but that did not work either. My current solution, a switch statement using `field.getType()`, is absolute garbage. Is there a cleaner, one-line solution to this?

Comment: Unsure if this is a duplicate, but a very similar question is here (with answers that should help): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891970/getting-default-value-for-primitive-types

Comment: `Array.get(Array.newInstance(field.getType(), 1), 0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting default value for primitive types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891970/getting-default-value-for-primitive-types)